# Literal transpose columns to single column rows

Tags: sql-server

TSQL question (MS Sql Server 2012) 
I have a table with rows that represent servers.  Each server has a back-up server for fail-over, so each row in my table has a column for the server ID (key) and a column representing the key of the server that is the designated back-up.

I've written a query against this table that finds mismatched rows, and that query returns three key values per row.  Each column is a key value that represents a server that is participating in a mismatch.  In most cases, we'll see three server s per mismatch - where server 1 shows it's pair is server 2, and server 2 has a pairing to a different server (server 3).

At present, I'm successfully finding mismatches as the following sample result shows:

```
    12345, 23456, 34567
    23424, 89234, 43453
```

The first column is the primary server ID, the second column is the current key for it's secondary, and the third column is the value that the secondary's row shows for its primary match.  When the third column is different than the first column, it's a mismatch, and I want to look at all of those rows in detail.

To do that examination, I want to use the results of the query that finds the ID's of rows that are mismatched in a subsequent select to get the details for each full record that the codes represent, such as

```
    select * from foo where foo.id in (12345, 23456, 34567, ...)
```

But, I don't know the ID's I want, so it would take the form of:

```
    select * from foo where foo.id in (subquery)
```

Due to wanting to use the results of my query as a set in a sub-query, the sub-query needs to return one value per row instead of three (I want to look at all three rows identified, as my use case is find records with data quality issues)

How do I get my results converted from columns to rows easily?  I don't have aggregation to do (thus pivot/unpivot seem out) - but for the select list I need the subquery to return distinct rows, one value per row instead of three values per row.

I know I could do a big-old-union, repeating the same complex self-join to find the three columns I need, one column at a time, calling them the same value.  The subquery that returns three values is somewhat expensive already, so I want to avoid that if possible.

It would seem all I need to do is transpose columns to rows - no calculations to do.  How?

Comment: Do any of these help?   https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=stack+overflow+sql+server+unpivot+without+aggregation&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4GGNI_enUS551US551&q=stack+overflow+sql+server+unpivot+without+aggregation&gs_l=hp....0.0.0.7612...........0.rpE0P9FNpf4

Answer (score 0):

Tab Alleman's hint got me to the answer I needed - Cross Apply gives you the ability to reformat results without aggregation.

For simplicity, my detail subquery can be condensed to:

```
    with foobar (code1, code2, code3)
    as
    ( 
        very complicated query that returns my results goes here 
    )

    select * from details where code in (select distinct u.code from foobar t
        cross apply
        (
            select code1
            union all
            select code2
            union all
            select code3
        ) u code )
```